# WordPress wp_insert_post with HTML in post_content is adding \r\n

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tinymce, sanitization

I'm creating a script outside of WordPress to insert new posts and WordPress is sanitizing my post in a weird way.

I will also be modifying the posts outside of WordPress.

**I'm am using TinyMCE for the `post_content` textarea.**

I'm using all WordPress functions by including:

`include('../wp-config.php');`

Here is my code that inserts my posts, but with \r\n for each new line:

```
$listing_phase = strtoupper($_POST['listing_phase']);
$listing_title = strtoupper($_POST['listing_title']);
$listing_description = $_POST['listing_description'];
$new_listing = array(
    'post_title'    => $listing_title,
    'post_name'     => str_replace('-', ' ', $listing_title),
    'post_content'  => $listing_description,
    'tax_input'     => array('property-status' => $listing_phase),
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_type'     => 'property',
    'post_author'   => 1
);
$listing_id = wp_insert_post($new_listing);
```

Here is the HTML that TinyMCE submitted:

```
<p>Studio</p>
<ul>
<li>Free Electric</li>
</ul>
```

This is what is in the database:

```
<p>Studio</p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>Free Electric</li>\r\n</ul>
```

When trying to modify a post I'm calling `the_content();` from `get_posts();` and \r\n are showing up.

How do I submit basic HTML content to WordPress's wp_insert_post function and get the content to view or modify later?

[image: WordPress Display]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $listing_description = str_replace('\r\n','',$_POST['listing_description']);
```